# Отсутствие переводов на странице закладок в профиле участника

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, профиль-участника, закладки

Заметил отсутствие переводов для двух строк:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Поискал здесь такие переводы, вроде нет таких вопросов.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ага, они давно уже планировали избранное переделать. Видимо, начали потихоньку выкатывать функционал.

Добавил переводы. Завтра-послезавтра появится.